# Styling values on the x-axis for D3.js created graphs

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a bar chart created with D3.js. One of the values on the x-axis is too long. I'm trying to add the CSS properties text-overflow: ellipsis, width: 10px and overflow: hidden so values that exceed a certain length are abbreviated. Doesn't seem to like this though. I can't set the width. of the  tag. I tried placing it in a container in the dev tools and applying the above listed properties to the container but that no work either. Here's the code:

```
<g class="tick" transform="translate(0, 10)" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line x2="-6" y2="0">
  <text x="-9" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">Longcat is looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</text>
</g>
```

I noticed that when the bar graph was created, the inline style text-anchor: end was added. I see what this does, placing the value name neatly beside the axis tick. But how can I style this text-tag so, for example "Longcat is looooooooooooooooooooong" only appears as "Longcat..."

Thx
--Gaweyne

Comment: You can't in SVG, you'll have to do the truncation yourself or use something like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cut your text before graph it.

```
d.name = (d.name.length > 7 ) ? d.name.substring(0, 7) + "..." : d.name;
```

Here's a working code: http://jsbin.com/baxilo/edit?html,output

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I considered doing something like this. But these are dynamically created graphs and it might involve a lot of fiddly things. But if there's no other way I guess I could try it.

Is there no CSS solution to this?

EDIT: Oh, Lars confirms above. Can't do this in an SVG.